# Car dealership landing page

Tags: javascript, angular.js

Please give feedback on what I could do better next time. This is an Angular 1.x landing page I made for a pretend car dealership.

[Here](https://capozzic1.github.io/angular-car-spa-v2/) is what it looks like.

Here is the app.js:

```
(function(){

'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('myApp',[]);



})();
```

Here is my car-slide.js directive that holds some car data, and has a controller for changing the current car picture and tagline:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('carSlide', CarSlide);


function CarSlide(){
return {
   restrict: 'E',
   templateUrl: 'partials/car-slide.html',
   controller:function($interval){


    this.currentCar = 0;
    var self = this;


    function changeCar(){
      if (self.currentCar == 0){
        self.currentCar = 1;
      } else {
        self.currentCar = 0;
      }
    }

    $interval(changeCar, 4000);

    this.carData = [{
                    class:'A4',
                    name: "Audi A4",
                    tagline: "The time is now.",
                    img: "img/big/car1.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                    class:'A5',
                    name: "Audi A5",
                    tagline: "Do you like power?",
                    img: "img/big/car2.jpg"}
                  ];

  },
  controllerAs:'carCtrl'
};

};
```

Here is the directive for the slider on the bottom. All it does is change the header from one car type to another:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('carTypeSlide', CarTypeSlide);

function CarTypeSlide() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'partials/car-type-slide.html',

        controller: function($interval) {
            var self = this;
            this.carTypes = [
                "Sedans",
                "Crossovers and Minivans",
                "Hybrids",
                "Compacts"
            ];
            var initial = 0;
            var currType = 0;
            this.showType = this.carTypes[initial];


            $interval(changeType, 3000);


            function changeType() {

                currType++;

                self.showType = self.carTypes[currType];

                if (currType === self.carTypes.length) {
                    currType = 0;
                    self.showType = self.carTypes[currType];
                }

            }


        },
        controllerAs: 'carTypeCtrl'
    };
};
```

[Here](https://github.com/capozzic1/angular-car-spa-v2) is the repo for it.

I have put AngularJS on pause and am trying to learn ES2015 right now, and then building a simple app with that. Do you think learning ES2015 will help with frameworks like Angular/React?

Comment: First of all, what are you doing should be not `directives`, but `components`. Directives (by new metodology) should be used to change element, not to create new. About ES2015 - in my opinion it's better to use it via Babel for now. And it helps to write Angular 1.6 in Angular 2 style. Better for a later transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of your carousel written in Angular 1.6 style with ES2015

```
(function(){
    class componentController {

        constructor($interval) {

            Object.assign(this, { $interval })

            this.currentCar = 0;

            this.carData = [
                {
                    class:'A4',
                    name: "Audi A4",
                    tagline: "The time is now.",
                    img: "img/big/car1.jpg"
                },
                {
                    class:'A5',
                    name: "Audi A5",
                    tagline: "Do you like power?",
                    img: "img/big/car2.jpg"
                }
            ];

            this.$interval(changeCar, 4000);
        }

        changeCar(){
            // this way you can have collection of any size
            this.currentCar = this.currentCar++ % this.carData.length;
        }
    }

    const componentOptions = {

        templateUrl: 'partials/car-slide.html',
        controller: componentController

    };

    angular.module('myApp').component('carSlide', componentOptions);

}());
```

ConrollerAs is `$ctrl` by default.